# Evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\sin x)^2}{(\cos x + \sin x)} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Need to integrate this function. Need help with my assignment. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos x+\sin x}dx$ and $J = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\cos^2x}{\cos x+ \sin x}dx$. Then you can evaluate: $I+J, J-I$ quicky and then **solve** for $I$

Comment: $$\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx\implies I=J$$

Comment: How would you find $I+J$ efficiently?

Comment: hint: $\displaystyle \int \sec xdx = ?$

Comment: You mean the method $\#1$ in my answer?

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Use $I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$\implies I+I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx+\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx=\int_a^b[f(x)+f(a+b-x)]\ dx$

Then

**Method** $\#1:A\cos x+B\sin x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos\left(x-\arctan \dfrac BA\right)$

**Method** $\#2:$    [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Integration_techniques/Tangent_Half_Angle)

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx$$
$$\Rightarrow 2I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx=2\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x}\,dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec x\,dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\ln\left(\sec x+\tan x\right)\right|_0^{\pi/4}=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)}$$